# Possible to scroll to a row in a table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a set of about 4000 records.  I display 15 at a time in a table and I am curious if there is anyway to implement a "scroll animation" that would allow users to scroll to a specific position in the table?

For example if the user was viewing records 1-15 and they wanted to view the 2000-2015 records is there a plugin that would make the records appear to scroll down to that position.

Also, would doing this cause performance problems (since I would potentially be loading 4000 records)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two separate questions here.

First check out a grid plugin that can handle huge data sets. This is usually done with virtual rendering.
I like [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) (among [many other places](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Used-by), it's used to display query results in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)).

Then you can figure out how to scroll to a particular row, since this will almost certainly depend on the grid implementation itself.

Comment: SlickGrid looks promising, but I am having trouble finding resources for it.  Take a look at this related question if you have a moment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473621/good-tutorial-for-slickgrid

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. You could think of also generating an anchor `<a>` per row, so you could just scroll to a specific place.

Here is a plugin that does that for you: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: +1 I have used scrollto in quite a few projects and it's rock solid!

Comment: It's rather unnecessary to generate an extra element per row, and with a large number of DOM elements, you really want to minimize overheard. Just add a unique ID to each row, like `<tr id="mytable-row-42>...</tr>`.

Comment: I don't know what's possible with ScrollTo, so yeah if you can just scroll to a `tr`, that's fine with me too. But I was thinking of anchors, because that is normally a logical place to scroll to.