# Good tutorial for SlickGrid?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am interested in getting familiar with SlickGrid but the only info I can find seems to be examples and the source code.  Can anyone recommend a good source for documentation and tutorials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using SlickGrid for a few weeks now and could not find a decent tutorial. I learned mostly from the examples included in the distribution, SlickGrid's source code & Firebug and [SlickGrid's Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/slickgrid) and... Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that is my best option.  Hope they get some decent documentation going soon.  Looks very promising.